# How to pass the out put of BSF sampler as in input to Beanshell scripting

Tags: jmeter

```
Hi I need to pass the output of BSF sampler as input  to the Bean shell pre-processor below are my programs
```

BSF sampler:

```
function makeid()
        {    
            var ts = new Date().getTime();
            var digits = 10e10; 
            //var timestamp = ts.toString() + Math.floor(Math.random() *digits ).toString(); 
            var timestamp = new Date().getTime().toString() + Math.floor(Math.random() *digits ).toString();
            return timestamp;
         }

function test()
{

        var uniqueId=makeid();

        var numCopies = 20,status = 'done printing',timestampDonePrintingAttr = "timestamp done printing",Title='demo.jpg',Username='keshavka'
        date='1429036296',printstatus='OK',time='1429036296';
        var joblog = {};        
        joblog[uniqueId] = {};
        joblog[uniqueId]['NumCopies'] = numCopies;
        joblog[uniqueId]['Status'] = status;
        joblog[uniqueId]['Title'] = Title;
        joblog[uniqueId]['Username'] = Username;
        joblog[uniqueId]['date'] = date;
        joblog[uniqueId]['print status'] = printstatus;
        joblog[uniqueId]['time'] = time;
        joblog[uniqueId]['timestampDonePrintingAttr'] = new Date().getTime();
        //console.log(i);

        var json = JSON.stringify(joblog);      

  return json;
}
```

Bean Shell Program  :

```
 FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter("C:\\apache-jmeter-2.13\\detail_log7.txt",false);
    BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);
    out.write(${test});
    out.close();
```

BSF sampler gives me a JSON and i need to create a File using Bean shell scripting and write content to it .
please help me through this

Answer (score 0):

Approaches may differ depending on where BSF Sampler and Beanshell PreProcessor live.

If Beanshell PreProcessor is a child of BSF Sampler - it won't play as PreProcessors are executed before samplers.

For other cases:

If you look at the top of "Script" input you'll see some pre-defined variables names like `ctx`, `vars`, `props`, etc.

[image: Beanshell vars]

For instance, `vars` stands for [JMeterVariables](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html) class instance, so you can set variable in BSF Sampler and access it in Beanshell PreProcessor as:

In BSF:

```
vars.put('json', json);
```

In Beanshell:

```
out.write(vars.get("json"));
```

If above approach won't help update the question with screenshot of your test plan.

NB:

- You don't need to switch to Beanshell just for writing JSON to file. See [Using Java From Scripts](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/scripting/prog_guide/javascript.html) guide to learn how you can access Java classes from JavaScript and vice versa
- Pre-defined variables like ctx, vars, props, etc. are described in detail in the [How to use BeanShell: JMeter's favorite built-in component](https://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) guide.
- Both JavaScript and Beanshell have performance problems so if this code is executed with more than i.e. 10 threads it is recommended to use [JSR223 test elements and Groovy](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) for scripting where required.